# Failed to create file - excel to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oledb

I have the next code:

```
   <asp:gridview id="GridView1" runat="server" cellpadding="6" gridlines="None" 
    bordercolor="#336699" borderstyle="Solid" borderwidth="1px">

    <headerstyle backcolor="#336699" font-bold="True" forecolor="White" />
    </asp:gridview>
```

And code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|App_Data|Machreta.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";

    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

    DataSet excelDataSet = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, strConn);

    da.Fill(excelDataSet);

    GridView1.DataSource = excelDataSet;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

I'm get the error:

> Failed to create file

To the line:

> ```
>     da.Fill(excelDataSet);
> ```

why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
string strConn = 
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
    @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Machreta.xls;" +
    @"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
```

or

```
string strConn = 
    @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
    @"Data Source=|App_Data|\Machreta.xls;" +
    @"Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
```

I splitted strings over many rows just for easy reading.

Comment: Hi thanks. i got that error:  "CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence" for the both options.

Comment: And now, after your edit, the first error is back: "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException failed to create file" .

Comment: The excel file is on hebrew language... can be the problem?

Comment: @Bside: are you sure that file is really there and that connection got opened correctly? Try manually opening connection and check this is correct...

Comment: Oh... now i see that the file is xlsx and not xls. i've changed it and now i got : "'Sheet1$' is not a valid name"

Comment: @Bside: According to [this link](http://codehill.com/2009/01/reading-excel-2003-and-2007-files-using-oledb/) your syntax seems correct. Are you sure in that file you have a sheet called **Sheet1**?

Comment: Yes. now the "failed to create file" is back. what is goin on with that. when i open the xls file with the page.aspx i got the error - that the file is in use.. so - the path is correct ...

Comment: @Bside: I see you'really confused. Calm yourself and try thinking about what you're doing. _File is in use_ means you've already opened it with Excel or (maybe) running another instance of somewhat: try to use Unlocker to find who's using your file and free it! Then (giving the fact that file path is right now) check that a sheet called **Sheet1** is really inside your file.

Comment: that's the tutorial that i took the code from: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1553779

Comment: @Bside: tutorial is ok, but you should always edit it to reflect your real needs or situation. Also remmeber you should close connection when you finished your work, or file could remain locked. Let me know. Anyway I think that this post is to be accepted and closed because the answer has been replied. Other problems could be posted with other questions.

Comment: You right ! i was really confuesd ! i forgot what is sheet means ... oops :). work great !